# jquery install -- copy/paste vs download linked file

Tags: jquery

When installing jquery from the website, the files are different when I copy/paste from the browser window vs right clicking and choosing download linked file. Why is this? Which way is right?

(I know they are different because of git diff.)

Comment: Both should be fine; what differences does the diff show?

Comment: It just shows line 16 being different, but this is a minified file so it is hard to tell.

Comment: Hmm. You might consider using a diff tool such as kdiff3 that can highlight differences within lines. That way you might be able to tell which individual characters are different between the files.

Comment: It looks like it is just whitespace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is technically no "right" way, but I don't think copy/pasting them into your own Javascript file would be the best route. I'm not sure whether you're pasting it into a Javascript file that has a number of other functions that you have made or whether you're pasting it into its own separate file, but in either case I think right-clicking and choosing download as would be your best bet.

Aside from that I would recommend using a CDN instead of actually hosting the file locally. jQuery is available on a number of CDNs and using one is relatively safe as they are pretty widespread (meaning if the CDN goes down there are going to be a LOT of broken web sites, not just yours). Using a CDN makes it so that you don't have to go download / upload the file to your web server every time there is an update and it also makes it so that some of your visitors may already have the file cached. For instance:

1) Person A visits website A which is also pointing to the CDN version of the latest version of jQuery. They browse that site for a bit

2) Person A visits your website which points to the jQuery CDN version. They do not have to get the file again because the browser notices that both references are the same and therefore loads the file that has been cached.

In doing so you can cut down on your own bandwidth (albeit a minimal amount unless you're talking thousands of visitors a day) and lighten the burden of maintenance on your end as well.

Just my opinion though. Cheers

**EDIT**

CDN = Content Delivery Network if you didn't already know.

Comment: Thanks, I can't used a cdn as it needs to be able to work from localhost without a network connection. But thanks for the info.